# PHP dynamic $_POST variable

Tags: php

I wish to get the $_POST value of a text box with in a form.

The name of the of the text box changes based on the user it is associated with.

```
<input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.mondstart' value='$tmpmonStart' placeholder='Start' size='3' maxlength='5'>
```

i.e. name would = bing.lee.mondstart

I have tried using:

```
$tmp = $tmpUsername . $_POST['mondstart']
$tmp = $_POST[$tmpUsername . 'mondstart']
```

Thank you.

Full source code:

```
echo "<form name='employeehours' method='post' action='../path/'>\n";
echo "<table align=center width=210 border=0 cellpadding=7 cellspacing=0 id='createformtable'>\n";



while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$timeformat = "hh:mm";
$tmpUsername = $row['Username'];
$tmpmonStart = substr($row['monStart'], 0, 5);
$tmpmonStop = substr($row['monStop'], 0, 5);
$tmptueStart = substr($row['tueStart'], 0, 5);
$tmptueStop = substr($row['tueStop'], 0, 5);
$tmpwedStart = substr($row['wedStart'], 0, 5);
$tmpwedStop = substr($row['wedStop'], 0, 5);
$tmpthuStart = substr($row['thuStart'], 0, 5);
$tmpthuStop = substr($row['thuStop'], 0, 5);
$tmpfriStart = substr($row['friStart'], 0, 5);
$tmpfriStop = substr($row['friStop'], 0, 5);
$tmpsatStart = substr($row['satStart'], 0, 5);
$tmpsatStop = substr($row['satStop'], 0, 5);
$tmpsunStart = substr($row['sunStart'], 0, 5);
$tmpsunStop = substr($row['sunStop'], 0, 5);


echo "<tr class='border_bottom'>\n";
echo "<td colspan=14><input type='checkbox' name='users[]' value='$tmpUsername'> #$tmpUsername</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td colspan=2 align='center'>Monday</td>\n";
echo "<td colspan=2 align='center'>Tuesday</td>\n";
echo "<td colspan=2 align='center'>Wednesday</td>\n";
echo "<td colspan=2 align='center'>Thursday</td>\n";
echo "<td colspan=2 align='center'>Friday</td>\n";
echo "<td colspan=2 align='center'>Saturday</td>\n";
echo "<td colspan=2 align='center'>Sunday</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.mondstart' value='$tmpmonStart' placeholder='Start' size='3' maxlength='5'></td> \n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.mondstop' value='$tmpmonStop' placeholder='Finish' size='3' maxlength='5'></td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.tuedstart' value='$tmptueStart' placeholder='Start' size='3' maxlength='5'></td> \n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.tuedstop' value='$tmptueStop' placeholder='Finish' size='3' maxlength='5'></td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.weddstart' value='$tmpwedStart' placeholder='Start' size='3' maxlength='5'></td> \n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.weddstop' value='$tmpwedStop' placeholder='Finish' size='3' maxlength='5'></td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.thudstart' value='$tmpthuStart' placeholder='Start' size='3' maxlength='5'></td> \n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.thudstop' value='$tmpthuStop' placeholder='Finish' size='3' maxlength='5'></td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.fridstart' value='$tmpfriStart' placeholder='Start' size='3' maxlength='5'></td> \n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.fridstop' value='$tmpfriStop' placeholder='Finish' size='3' maxlength='5'></td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.satdstart' value='$tmpsatStart' placeholder='Start' size='3' maxlength='5'></td> \n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.satdstop' value='$tmpsatStop' placeholder='Finish' size='3' maxlength='5'></td>\n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.sundstart' value='$tmpsunStart' placeholder='Start' size='3' maxlength='5'></td> \n";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='$tmpUsername.sundstop' value='$tmpsunStop' placeholder='Finish' size='3' maxlength='5'></td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr><td colspan='14' style='height: 5%;'></td></tr>";
}

echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td colspan='14' align = center><input type = submit></td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
echo "</form>";



if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$updateUsers = $_POST['users'];

foreach($updateUsers as $user){
var_dump($user);
$tmp = $_POST[$user . '.mondstart'];

//$tmp =  $_POST[$user.'mondstart'];
echo $tmp;

echo $user;

}
```

Comment: $new_var = $user.mondstart; $tmp=$_POST["$new_var"]; try this way

Comment: @jewelhuq Still returns no value. :(  foreach($updateUsers as $user){
    $new_var = $user.mondstart;
    $tmp=$_POST["$new_var"];
    


//$tmp =  $_POST[$user.'mondstart'];
echo $tmp;
}

Comment: Is $updateUsers is one dimensional array? Can you show var_dump($updateUsers) output. Also print_r($_POST).

Comment: @SumitPatil 

print_r($_POST)

Array ( [users] => Array ( [0] => bing.lee [1] => sung.sam ) 
[bing_lee_mondstart] => 06:00 [bing_lee_mondstop] => 15:00 

) Array ( [users] => Array ( [0] => bing.lee [1] => sung.sam 
) [bing_lee_mondstart] => 06:00 [bing_lee_mondstop] => 15:00 
)

var_dump($updateUsers) 

array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "bing.lee" [1]=> string(19) "sun.sam" } array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "bing.lee" [1]=> string(19) "sung.sam" }

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if either is an array. If they're strings try the concatenating assignment operator instead.

```
foreach($updateUsers as $user){

$tmp = $user;
$tmp .= $_POST['mondstart'];

echo $tmp;
}
```

Also,

```
$tmp = $user . $_POST['mondstart'];
```

should work. But if you need a space between,

```
$tmp = $user." ".$_POST['mondstart'];
```

If either is an array you will need to use `implode()`.

Comment: Thank you, although the above solution returned null variables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the name attribute is correct and is like `name='bing.lee.mondstart'` in the source (please make sure it is by viewing the source of the page in the browser), **you are missing the dot** in the `$_POST` variable. So try using the following statement:

```
$tmp = $_POST[$tmpUsername . '.mondstart'];
```

And the `$tmp` variable will have the value you need.

Comment: Thank you, although $tmp is still empty. Source code: <input type='text' name='bing.lee.mondstart' value='06:00' placeholder='Start' size='3' maxlength='5'>

Comment: @henPHP just before assigning the $tmp variable please echo out or var_dump() $tmpUsername and see if it has `bing.lee` in it or something else. Also if possible please add the full form code in the question and it will be more easier to find the error..

Comment: string(8) "bing.lee" I have edited my original post.